# Restangular + Sails.js + CORS = server requests are firing twice

Tags: cors, sails.js, restangular

I'm using sails.js on my server (0.10.1) with CORS enabled.
On my client I use restangular (1.4.0).

For each request I make, the client sends it twice, once as an OPTION and once as GET/POST.

So far this is normal, but it seems the sails is not handling the OPTION request well, as it fires the request twice.

I tried adding:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({withCredentials: true});
RestangularProvider.setDefaultRequestParams('jsonp', {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'});
```

And I'm sure the client is only firing the request once.

I have no idea how to start debugging this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Restangular all good until trying to send params to qualify a getList().  I had to allow new header items in Sails. ? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2043) on Github.  It has been patched and will be in an upcoming patch release of Sails.  In the meantime, an easy workaround is to just put the following in your **config/routes.js** file:

```
"OPTIONS /*": function (req, res) {res.send(200);}
```

**Update**

This is fixed in v0.10.2, so you should no longer have to specify your own `OPTIONS` route.